# How to run only a section of R markdown file based on parameter?

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown

I am trying to only run a specific section of an R markdown file, based on the value of a parameter. For example, in this R markdown file that is adapted from the R markdown typical example (I did not close the r chunks with the '```' symbol in the example as it closes the code area in the StackOverflow question):

````
---
title: "Untitled"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: pdf_document
params: 
  CategReport:
    label: "Report with plots?"
    value: Choose type of report
    input: select
    multiple: true
    choices: [Plots, Text]
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)


## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)


if Plots %not in% params$CategReport, don't run the area from below, continue after it ->

{ ### PLOT AREA START

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)

### PLOT AREA END}

## Other stuff that will be printed regardless if plot area is skipped or not
````

What I want is that, if the user chooses the 'Plots' choice in the multiple choice question when knitting with parameters, everything below the 'if Plots %in% params$CategReport, run everything from below ->' will be shown, including the text outside the code chunk.

I've seen some options online to include conditional code chunks based on parameter value, but if I do that I can only include the text in the code chunk. And if I include text in the code chunk, I don't know how to access all the nice R markdown formats like "##" or "**" and the nice text orientation on the page. If I do it in the code chunk, it will appear like code comments.

So I am looking into putting a condition, that, if not met, will skip this entire section of the report, but still show the part of the markdown that is below this part (e.g. '## Other stuff that will be printed regardless if plot area is skipped or not').

Basically, I am looking for something like: if condition met, skip or don't skip this section of the markdown - if not skipped, print it as normal, if skipped, print everything before and after this section (and crucially, this section includes both stuff outside code chunks and stuff inside code chunks).

Is it possible to have something like this?

Comment: How different are the things you want to do for each option? Do they have any common pattern?  Each time you run the report it would be exactly one parameter varying?

Comment: Thanks! So basically the report is a bunch of graphs I make, and I want allow the user to customize it (add/remove one graph,etc). The common pattern they have is that I need to run a script before to create the graphs, and then I just plot them in individual chunks. Each time the report runs can have different settings depending on the multiple-choice answer options of the user. Basically with child RMDs, I'd need one RMD for each answer option, which I think is a bit tedious here. Either that or be fine with text in code chunks (which can be shown conditionally), the way I understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to use a child document and pass a condition to the `eval=` chunk option so that the child document only gets rendered when the user selects `"Plots"`:

````
---
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: pdf_document
params: 
  CategReport:
    label: "Report with plots?"
    value: Choose type of report
    input: select
    multiple: true
    choices: [Plots, Text]
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

```{r eval="Plots" %in% params$CategReport, child = "child.Rmd"}
```

Other stuff that will be printed regardless if plot area is skipped or not
````

**child.Rmd**

````
## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```
````

Comment: Thanks! This works!:) The only issue I think that is not a scalable solution for large code. In my case, I want to have this conditional with ~10 answer options, which means creating 10 child Rmds. Still doable, but ideally I could do all in one... Thanks a lot!:)

Comment: You might find that in fact it will give you a lot more flexibility to add or removed options if you do it with child files, especially if you match the parameter names to the child names so that the file names are created dynamically.

Comment: See https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/child-document.html

Comment: Thanks a lot! Indeed, it seems to work very well - what do you mean by 'match the parameter names to the child names so that the file names are created dynamically'? Do you mean that the RMD gets created dynamically only if the parameter is true or something like that?